# curl request headers in Apache default error_logs

Tags: php, curl

some uncontrolled logging on the web server inside apache error_log

```
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: max=10
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Set-Cookie: BIGipServerabcd_prod_serv=4116270402.20480.0000; expires=Thu, 03-Apr-2014 00:19:32 GMT; path=/
* Connection #0 to host services.abcd.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* About to connect() to services.abcd.com port 80
*   Trying 99.97.124.97... * connected
* Connected to services.abcd.com (99.97.124.97) port 80 here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the verbose output from curl. Generated for this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

So find this line from your code and make it `0` or `false`(only if you do not wish to see the prints). Or simply delete this.

Comment: Thanks Sabuj,Right those information messages are request headers in error_logs, whenever curl makes an outbound request to other domains like services.abcd.com or api.abcdservices.com it captures header info in apache error log by default.
 
I have disabled those headers call info by changing
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,0);
for outbound domain in the application code.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. I learned it from you just now.